# How to read serial data with multiprocessing in python?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue, python-multiprocessing, pyserial

I have a device that outputs data at irregular intervals. I want to write data onto a csv in 2 second intervals. So I figured multiprocessing with a queue might work.

Here I'm trying to just pass data from one process to another but I get Serial Exception. Also, I'm unable to run it on IDLE. So I'm stuck with using the terminal. As a result, the error message closes as soon as it opens.

Here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime
import serial

try:
    fio2_ser = serial.Serial("COM3",
                baudrate=2400,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                parity =serial.PARITY_ODD)

except serial.SerialException:
        print("FiO2 Analyser Device not detected")   


def Read_Data(q):
    global fio2_ser

    while True:

        try:                    
            fio2_data = fio2_ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
            fio2_data = str(fio2_data).replace("\r\n","")
            fio2_data = fio2_data.replace("\x000","")

        except:
                fio2_data = "FiO2 Data Unavailable"

        q.put(fio2_data)

def Disp_Data(q):

    while q.empty() is False:

        fio2_data = q.get()
        print(fio2_data)

        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Read_Data, args=(q,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Disp_Data, args=(q,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

When I run a separate module to collect data, it runs fine and collects data.

```
import serial

try:
    fio2_ser = serial.Serial("COM3",
                baudrate=2400,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                parity =serial.PARITY_ODD)

except serial.SerialException:
        print("FiO2 Analyser Device not detected")   

def Reader():
    global fio2_ser
    try:                    
        fio2_data = fio2_ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        fio2_data = str(fio2_data).replace("\r\n","")
        fio2_data = fio2_data.replace("\x000","")
        return fio2_data
    except:
            return "FiO2 Data Unavailable"

if __name__ =='__main__':
    value = Reader()
    print(value)
```

Comment: Which platform? Is this windows? You open the serial port at the module level before starting subprocesses. Shouldn't that just be in the serial reader function?

Comment: Initialize your whole serial interface in the `Read_Data()` _process_ - once launched it doesn't share the connection established in your main process.

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows. And no, it didn't work. I put it inside the try block of the Read_data function. Still the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Disp_Data() function will stop running when q.empty() is True. In my case the loop exits immediately.

Might be useful to display the error message thrown by SerialException to see the cause:

```
except serial.SerialException as msg:
        print( "Error opening serial port %s" % msg)
```

Also, it would be better to gracefully shut down the child-processes. In my case, they kept running after killing the main process, so the Read_Data() process keeps the port open.

**The multiprocessing module doesn't like pickling pyserial.**

This following code snip works on my Windows10 box

- Used threading instead.
- Added some print statements here ad there to understand what is
  happening.
- Used multiprocessing.Event() to improve shutdown.
- Print exception error messages to see what causes serial exceptions.
- One second timeout on serial port to allow read loop to continue.

  - Maybe not necessary for release code.

```
import threading, multiprocessing
import time
import serial
import sys


def OpenSerialPort(port=""):
    print ("Open port %s" % port)

    fio2_ser = None

    try:
        fio2_ser = serial.Serial(port,
                    baudrate=2400,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    parity =serial.PARITY_ODD)

    except serial.SerialException as msg:
        print( "Error opening serial port %s" % msg)

    except:
        exctype, errorMsg = sys.exc_info()[:2]
        print ("%s  %s" % (errorMsg, exctype))

    return fio2_ser


def Read_Data(queue, serialPort, stopped):
    print ("Start reading data.")

    serialPort.timeout = 1.0
    while not stopped.is_set(): 
        fio2_data = ''       
        try:                    
            #print "Reading port..."
            fio2_data = serialPort.readline()

        except:
            exctype, errorMsg = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            print ("Error reading port - %s" % errorMsg)
            stopped.set()
            break

        if len(fio2_data) > 0:
            fio2_data = fio2_data.decode('utf-8')
            fio2_data = str(fio2_data).replace("\r\n","")
            fio2_data = fio2_data.replace("\x000","")
            queue.put(fio2_data)
        else:
            queue.put("Read_Data() no Data")

    serialPort.close()
    print ("Read_Data finished.")

def Disp_Data(queue, stopped):
    print ("Disp_Data started")
    while not stopped.is_set():
        #print "Check message queue."
        if queue.empty() == False:        
            fio2_data = queue.get()
            print(fio2_data)

    print ("Disp_Data finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":


    #serialPort = OpenSerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0')
    serialPort = OpenSerialPort('COM3')
    if serialPort == None: sys.exit(1)

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    stopped = threading.Event()
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=Read_Data, args=(queue, serialPort, stopped,))
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=Disp_Data, args=(queue, stopped,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    loopcnt = 20
    while (loopcnt > 0) and (not stopped.is_set()):
        loopcnt -= 1
        print ("main() %d" % loopcnt)
        try:
            time.sleep(1)

        except KeyboardInterrupt: #Capture Ctrl-C
            print ("Captured Ctrl-C")
            loopcnt=0
            stopped.set()

    stopped.set()
    loopcnt=0        

    print ("Stopped")
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    serialPort.close()
    print ("Done")
```

Comment: you use thread instead of process problem is process can not accept serialPort as  argument so better to implement serialport in readdata