# how to run multiple .py files with infinite loop from a python module?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, executable, pyserial

I have two files. Let's call it file_X.py and file_Y.py. Both have infinite loops that continuously read data from COM ports. I have a tkinter module with two buttons to launch file_X and file_Y. So if I click button A, I want file_X to run and button B would launch file_Y. How can I run these files in parallel and have them display the data in their respective command prompt terminals?

I tried using runpy and os.system. os.system would throw me an error even though the modules for both files were working fine on their own. On the other hand, runpy wouldn't let me click on the other button while the first module was running.

Tkinter module:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

import runpy

root = tk.Tk()
root. title("App")
root.geometry('700x500')

v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(-1)

button_labels = [
    (" Device 1 "),
    (" Device 2 ")]

def ShowChoice():
    choice = v.get() + 1
    if(choice == 1):
        runpy.run_module('file_X', run_name='__main__')

    elif(choice == 2):
        runpy.run_module('file_Y', run_name='__main__')

tk.Label(root, 
         text="""Choose the device you want to launch:""",
         font = 'Arial 20 bold',
         justify = tk.LEFT,
         height = 6,
         padx = 20).pack()

for val, button_label in enumerate(button_labels):
    tk.Radiobutton(root,
                   text = button_label,
                   font = 'Times 12 bold',
                   indicatoron = 0,
                   bg = 'cornflower blue',
                   width = 40,
                   padx = 20,
                   pady = 5,
                   variable=v,
                   command=ShowChoice,
                   value=val).pack(anchor=tk.S)

root.mainloop()
```

file_X and file_Y have pretty much the same code but are connected to different COM Ports and have different string modifications.

```
import serial
import time
import csv

try:
ser = serial.Serial("COM4",
                     baudrate=2400,
                     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                     parity =serial.PARITY_ODD)

except:
        print("Device not detected")   

def Reader():
    global ser
    try:                    
        data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        data = str(data).replace("\r\n","")
        data = data.replace("\x000","")
        return data
    except:
        return "Data Unavailable"

def Start():
    date_now = time.strftime('%d.%m.%y')
    time_now = time.strftime('%H.%M.%S')
    file_name = date_now + '__' + time_now + '.csv'

    with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
        csv_file = csv.writer(f)
        csv_file.writerow(['DATE','TIME','VALUE'])  

        while True:
            date_now = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
            time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            data = Reader()
            csv_file.writerow([date_now, time_now, data])
            print([date_now, time_now, data])

if __name__ =='__main__':

    Start()
```

Comment: We will need some example code to work with. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is likely you will need to look into multi-threading. Assuming your 2 `py` files are in the same folder you can import them just like a library. `import _X as x` or something like that. And then execute the code inside by referencing its name like `x.some_function_name(arguments)`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I tried using multithreading and multiprocessing but it in both cases it kept throwing me serialExceptions

Comment: The only way you are going to get these to scripts to run in parallel (that  I am aware of) is through multi-threading. Otherwise only one can run at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the threading, multiprocessing or subprocess modules.

Here is a quick sample which demonstrates the threading module.

```
import threading, time

def Start(name=''):
    cnt=0
    while(cnt<10):
        cnt+=1
        print "This is thread %s" % name
        time.sleep(1)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Start, name='Thread-1', args=('Serial1',))

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=Start, name='Thread-2', args=('Serial2',))

thread2.start()
thread1.start()


while (thread1.isAlive() and thread2.isAlive()):
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Running Threads : %s" % [thread.name for thread in threading.enumerate()]


print "done"
```

As suggested you could import file_X and file_Y and create a thread for each using the Start() function as the target (callable object) to be invoked by the run() method of each thread.

```
import file_X, file_Y

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=file_X.Start, name='COM1') 
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=file_Y.Start, name='COM2')
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

The multiprocessing module is similar to threading.

Alternatively run file_X and file_Y as subprocesses using the subprocess module.

> > > > NEW <<<<
> > > >         Here is a solution using threading. I've only tested it with one port.

```
import threading
import time
import serial
import sys, os.path
import csv


def OpenSerialPort(port=""):
    print ("Open port %s" % port)

    serPort = None

    try:
        serPort = serial.Serial(port,
                    baudrate=2400,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    parity =serial.PARITY_ODD)

    except serial.SerialException as msg:
        print( "Error opening serial port %s" % msg)

    except:
        exctype, errorMsg = sys.exc_info()[:2]
        print ("%s  %s" % (errorMsg, exctype))

    return serPort


def Reader(file_name, serialPort, stopped):
    print ("Start reading serial port %s." % serialPort.name)

    serialPort.timeout = 1.0
    while not stopped.is_set(): 
        serData = ''       
        try:                    
            #print "Reading port..."
            serData = serialPort.readline()

        except:
            exctype, errorMsg = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            print ("Error reading port - %s" % errorMsg)
            stopped.set()
            break

        if len(serData) > 0:
            serData = serData.decode('utf-8')
            serData = str(serData).replace("\r\n","")
            serData = serData.replace("\x000","")
            Log_Data(file_name, serData)
        #else:
        #    print("Reader() no Data")

    serialPort.close()
    print ("Reader finished. Closed %s" % serialPort.name)

def Init_Log(portName=''):
    #Create log file
    portName = os.path.basename(portName)
    file_name = time.strftime('%d.%m.%y__%H.%M.%S') + "__%s.csv" % portName
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        csv_file = csv.writer(f)
        csv_file.writerow(['DATE','TIME','VALUE'])

    return file_name    

def Log_Data(file_name='', dataString=''):

    date_now = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
    time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        csv_file = csv.writer(f)
        csv_file.writerow([date_now, time_now, dataString])
        print([date_now, time_now, dataString])



if __name__ == "__main__":

    stopped = threading.Event() # Create stopped event to notify all threads when it is time to stop.

    #Open COM3 ports
    portName = 'COM3'
    serialPort_1 = OpenSerialPort(portName)
    if serialPort_1 == None: 
        sys.exit(1)
    file_name_1 = Init_Log(portName) #Create log file

    p1 = threading.Thread(target=Reader, args=(file_name_1, serialPort_1, stopped,))


    #Open COM4 ports
    portName = 'COM4'
    serialPort_2 = OpenSerialPort(portName)
    if serialPort_2 == None: 
        sys.exit(1)
    #Create log file
    file_name_2 = Init_Log(portName)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=Reader, args=(file_name_2, serialPort_2, stopped,))


    #Start port reader threads
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    #This is just a test loop that does nothing for awhile.
    loopcnt = 20
    while (loopcnt > 0) and (not stopped.is_set()):
        loopcnt -= 1
        print ("main() %d" % loopcnt)

        try:
            time.sleep(1)

        except KeyboardInterrupt: #Capture Ctrl-C
            print ("Captured Ctrl-C")
            loopcnt=0
            stopped.set()

    stopped.set()
    print ("Stopped")
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    serialPort_1.close()
    serialPort_2.close()
    print ("Done")
```

Comment: thanks for the sample code. I tried something like this before.
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660594/how-to-read-serial-data-with-multiprocessing-in-python?noredirect=1#comment86331134_49660594 )
It kept throwing me SerialException. Do you think your algorithm would work for that too?

Comment: Might be handy to see what caused the exception: use exctype, errorMsg = sys.exc_info()[:2] in the except clause.

Comment: The new code snip is based on your other question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660594/how-to-read-serial-data-with-multiprocessing-in-python?noredirect=1#comment86331134_49660594