# High data-rate parallelism between python and arduino uno

Tags: python, parallel-processing, arduino, pyserial, arduino-uno

I'm working on a project where a data capture system sends EMG data to a python script through an Arduino Uno's serial port and the python script classifies the user's intent by processing a chunk of that data. The data capture system sends samples at 250Hz and I require my python script to not miss samples the capture system is sending while classifying.

For this I want two parallelly running processes:

1. A process continuously capturing the data and buffering it. (using PySerial) - running every 0.004s
2. A process taking data from the buffer, preprocess it and classifying it. - this process approximately takes 0.03 seconds to run per loop excluding data acquisition

I don't know how to proceed with this. I've tried and read through a lot of articles but to no avail.

I tried threading, but apparently threading is not true parallelism, so I gave up trying to make it work.
I tried using multiprocessing but [the multiprocessing module doesn't like pickling pyserial.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660594/how-to-read-serial-data-with-multiprocessing-in-python)

Here's what I tried: (It's probably full of mistakes, I hacked it up but I expected some output, also this is not indefinitely buffering, but I'm trying to get at least the first buffer printed)

Driver Code:

```
import GatherData as gd
import serial.tools.list_ports
from multiprocessing import Pool


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = []
    serialInst = serial.Serial()  
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    
    portList = []
    for Port in ports:
        portList.append(str(Port))
        print(str(Port))
        
    val = input("Select Port: COM")
    
    for x in range(0,len(portList)):
        if(portList[x].startswith("COM"+str(val))):
            portVar = "COM"+str(val)
            print(portList[x])
    serialInst.baudrate = 115200
    serialInst.port = portVar
    serialInst.open()
    
    p = Pool(6)  # Number of concurrent processes
    arr = p.starmap(gd.collect, (arr, serialInst)) # Start all processes
    p.map(gd.printnum(arr))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

GatherData.py:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# import Dependencies as dp

def collect(array,serialInst):
    ch = 4
    if not array:
        return makearr()
    else:
        nextw = array[1:]
        temparr = []
        if (serialInst.in_waiting):
            packet = serialInst.readline()
            # now = time.time()
            line_as_list = packet.split(b'\t')
            #print(line_as_list)
            for i in range(1,ch+1):
                try:
                    rand1=line_as_list[i]
                    #print("rand1", rand1)
                    rand1List = rand1.split(b'\n')
                    rand1f = float(rand1List[0])
                    temparr.append(rand1f)
                    #print(temparr)
                except IndexError:
                    return collect(array) #add pca
                except ValueError:
                    return collect(array) #add pca
                
            nextw.append(temparr)
            print(nextw)
            return nextw

def makearr(serialInst):
    final = []
    counter = 0
    while(counter<50):
        temparr = []
        if (serialInst.in_waiting):
            packet = serialInst.readline()
            line_as_list = packet.split(b'\t')
            flag = 0
            for i in range(1,5):
                try:
                    rand1=line_as_list[i]
                    #print("rand1", rand1)
                    rand1List = rand1.split(b'\n')
                    rand1f = float(rand1List[0])
                    temparr.append(rand1f)
                except IndexError:
                    flag = 1
                    continue
                except ValueError:
                    flag = 1
                    continue
                    
            if(flag == 0):
                final.append(temparr)
                counter=counter+1
    return final

def printnum(array):
    while True:
        if array:
            print(len(array), end='\r')
```

The errors:

```
COM8 - Arduino Uno (COM8)
Select Port: COM8
COM8 - Arduino Uno (COM8)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\indra\documents\igibup.py", line 34, in <module>
    arr = p.starmap(gd.collect, (arr, serialInst)) # Start all processes

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 276, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)

ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

I don't understand how to proceed.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example of your multiprocessing attempt.

Comment: Not sure of the specifics of your project, but you might consider adding a $5 Pico to buffer and maybe pre-process your data.